# Auto Format of completed row

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

This code should change all the text in a row to green if there is a value entered into column AD. However, this is not occurring automatically. *I should add that when the macro is run manually, the "completed" rows text does change to the correct color.* This code snippet was added into the Microsoft Excel Objects Sheet1. Another thing that occurs is the header row text gets colored when the macro is manually run. How do I stop the header row text from getting colored and have this macro run automatically?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    RowComplete
End Sub

Sub RowComplete()
    Dim row As Range
    For Each row In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
        If row.Cells(1, "AD").Value > 0 Then
            row.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        Else
            row.Font.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub 'don't change header color

If r.Cells(1, "D").Value <> "" Then 'change "D" to applicable column
    r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
Else
    r.Font.ColorIndex = xlNone
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you much for assisting with this. This achieved the results I was expecting.

Comment: Happy new Year. I noticed one issue but have not been able to get back to send a comment. If I put the date in cell AD (I did change the code to reflect this cell), it does as intended and changes the text color in the entire row. However, if I delete the cells contents, it does not revert back to black text. Should I change the Else to 'r.Font.ColorIndex = 1'?

Comment: Ok. I should have just done it and asked first. That is what was needed. Happy New Year anyway...lol

Comment: How can I add a second Worksheet_Change sub into the same workbook?

Comment: You can't. It's a built in event. You can add code to the event.